# HDFS + cant copy file from HDFS to local folder

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, rhel, ambari, hdp

we are trying to copy the file from `/hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292/hive/hive.tar.gz` to local folder `/var/tmp`

as we can see we get  `hdfs.DFSClient: Could not obtain` and `No live nodes contain current block Block locations: Dead nodes: . Throwing a BlockMissingException`

and finally the file not copied to local folder - `/var/tmp`

we also try to copy other files under `/hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292` to local folder - `/var/tmp`

but we get the same errors

any idea what could be the reason for this issues?

NOTE - we chacked the HDFS helth check from ambari and HDFS is fine

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal    /hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292/hive/hive.tar.gz /var/tmp
20/08/04 09:07:12 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: No node available for BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 file=/hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292/hive/hive.tar.gz
20/08/04 09:07:12 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Could not obtain BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 from any node: java.io.IOException: No live nodes contain block BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 after checking nodes = [], ignoredNodes = null No live nodes contain current block Block locations: Dead nodes: . Will get new block locations from namenode and retry...
20/08/04 09:07:12 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DFS chooseDataNode: got # 1 IOException, will wait for 916.7101213444472 msec.
20/08/04 09:07:12 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: No node available for BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 file=/hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292/hive/hive.tar.gz
20/08/04 09:07:12 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Could not obtain BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 from any node: java.io.IOException: No live nodes contain block BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 after checking nodes = [], ignoredNodes = null No live nodes contain current block Block locations: Dead nodes: . Will get new block locations from namenode and retry...
20/08/04 09:07:12 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DFS chooseDataNode: got # 2 IOException, will wait for 8364.841990287568 msec.
20/08/04 09:07:21 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: No node available for BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 file=/hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292/hive/hive.tar.gz
20/08/04 09:07:21 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Could not obtain BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 from any node: java.io.IOException: No live nodes contain block BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 after checking nodes = [], ignoredNodes = null No live nodes contain current block Block locations: Dead nodes: . Will get new block locations from namenode and retry...
20/08/04 09:07:21 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DFS chooseDataNode: got # 3 IOException, will wait for 14554.977191829808 msec.
20/08/04 09:07:35 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not obtain block: BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 file=/hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292/hive/hive.tar.gz No live nodes contain current block Block locations: Dead nodes: . Throwing a BlockMissingException
20/08/04 09:07:35 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not obtain block: BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 file=/hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292/hive/hive.tar.gz No live nodes contain current block Block locations: Dead nodes: . Throwing a BlockMissingException
20/08/04 09:07:35 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DFS Read
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 file=/hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292/hive/hive.tar.gz
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.chooseDataNode(DFSInputStream.java:995)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:888)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:945)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination$TargetFileSystem.writeStreamToFile(CommandWithDestination.java:467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.copyStreamToTarget(CommandWithDestination.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.copyFileToTarget(CommandWithDestination.java:329)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPath(CommandWithDestination.java:264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPath(CommandWithDestination.java:249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:317)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPathArgument(Command.java:289)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPathArgument(CommandWithDestination.java:244)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArgument(Command.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArguments(Command.java:255)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processArguments(CommandWithDestination.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.FsCommand.processRawArguments(FsCommand.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:356)
copyToLocal: Could not obtain block: BP-551390946-23.1.22.254-1596451810664:blk_1073741831_1007 file=/hdp/apps/2.6.5.0-292/hive/hive.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please run the below command and check if blocks are corrupted?

```
hdfs fsck /
```

If there are corrupted blocks then you might need to follow a recovery process.
For recovery you can follow the link
https://blog.cloudera.com/understanding-hdfs-recovery-processes-part-1/